Repeated Permutation of Powers
Let's say I have two radix/base values x and y (both are floats, not ints) and I need to quickly generate all combinations of:
[xny0, xn-1y, xn-2y2, ..., x2yn-2, x1yn-1, x0yn]
where n is some integer between [50, 100]. Naively, I can do:
import math
values = []
for i in range(n+1):
   j = n - i
   values.append(math.pow(x, j) * math.pow(y, i))

However, I need to repeat this for over 400 million different combinations of (x, y, n). What is the fastest/most efficient way to go about this? Currently, I believe that this is O(m x n) where m is the total number of (x, y, n) tuples.

Of your combinations of (x,y,n) how many have the same x or y as another?

if the n is between 50 and 100 then that means something like >80 million x,y tuples. How many distinct values of x and  y are there? @Dogbert second method provides a way forward and you can generate sequence[n+1] from sequence[n] quickly.

@PeteKirkham Since x and y are floats, you can assume that x and y never repeat (i.e., all of the pairs are distinct)

Are you hoping for something better than O(m x n)?

I guess we could use NumPy to generate the values more quickly, but in NumPy arrays, and it's not clear whether that's good or bad for you, as we don't know what you're going to do with those values.

Since there are only 51 different values of n against 400 million combinations, it is clear that the fastest approach is to group the data by n and vectorize it using numpy. So the question is whether your data can be pre-grouped by n. If the data is streamed, such optimization would not be possible.

@ken The combinations can definitely be grouped. What did you have in mind? Could you provide an answer below?

@slaw Please add realistic examples of input and how you plan to use the generated values to the question so we can do more accurate benchmarks. I'm curious about how you plan to use 400 million lists. I'm also curious about the range of values for x and y. For example, if x=2.0, the first element will be about 1e+30, and the floating-point error for that could be more than 1e+14. It's small in relative terms, but large in absolute terms. Can you accept this error? Or do you need the most accurate result?

You can keep a temporary value initialized to be math.pow(x, n) and on every iteration, multiply it by y / x:
import math

x = 1.23
y = 4.56
n = 10

# Original Implementation
values = []
for i in range(n + 1):
    j = n - i
    values.append(math.pow(x, j) * math.pow(y, i))

# My Implementation
values2 = []
tmp = math.pow(x, n)
multiplier = y / x
for _ in range(n + 1):
    values2.append(tmp)
    tmp *= multiplier

print(values)
print(values2)

# Edited to add:
# My Implementation v2
values3 = [x**n]
multiplier = y / x
for _ in range(n):
    values3.append(values3[-1] * multiplier)
print(values3)

Output:
[7.92594609605189, 29.38399528292408, 108.93578739035267, 403.8595044715513, 1497.2352360896539, 5550.725753307984, 20578.300353727158, 76290.284238208, 282832.27327335643, 1048548.9155500043, 3887303.2966731866]
[7.92594609605189, 29.383995282924076, 108.93578739035266, 403.8595044715513, 1497.2352360896534, 5550.725753307983, 20578.300353727154, 76290.28423820798, 282832.27327335643, 1048548.9155500042, 3887303.296673186]
[7.92594609605189, 29.383995282924076, 108.93578739035266, 403.8595044715513, 1497.2352360896534, 5550.725753307983, 20578.300353727154, 76290.28423820798, 282832.27327335643, 1048548.9155500042, 3887303.296673186]

Note that due to how floating point math works, the values won't be exactly the same this way in practice even though the math operations we're doing are identical in theory.

@nocomment thanks for pointing it out, I accidentally removed some code when I added my v2 implementation.

@nocomment that was very strange. I still have the "403.85950447155125" output in my shell history but now I can't reproduce. Ran the script 1000 times just now and I cannot get that value again. Anyways I updated the output.

I think you did * y / x instead of the multiplier. That way I get those other numbers.

You can probably optimize a bit with values3 = [x**n] * (n+1) to allocate the whole list at once. Then assign elements with values3[i+1] = values3[i] * multiplier.

@nocomment ah yeah, that's it!

@Olivier I'd like to see a benchmark. Could also be slower.

This should be several times faster if used with numba.

Below is my suggested method, in large n it is faster than loop method:
import numpy as np
import math

def flipower(x,y,n):

    n_ = np.arange(n)
    n__ = np.flip(n_)
    X = np.ones((n,len(x))) * x
    X = X.T
    Y = np.ones((n,len(y))) * y
    Y = Y.T
    
    return list( np.power(X,n_)  * np.power(Y,n__) )

n = 50
x = np.array([2,3,4,4,5]) # definitely x and y are the same size due to x*y pair multiplication condition
y = np.array([5,7,8,9,10])
flipower(x,y,n)


to compare I tested your method for n=49 which is equal to n=50 in above method:
n = 49
x = np.array([2,3,4,4,5]) # definitely x and y are the same size due to x*y pair multiplication condition
y = np.array([5,7,8,9,10])

def loopower(n,x,y):
    values = []
    for xx in range(len(x)):
        for i in range(n+1):
            j = n - i
            values.append(math.pow(x[xx], j) * math.pow(y[xx], i))
    
    return values

loopower(n,x,y)



Disclaimer: I'm not at my computer right now to test. But this is how I would do it using numpy.
import numpy as np

values = []
# pairs is a list of (x, y, n) tuples
for x, y, n in pairs:
    powers = np.arange(n+1)
    res = (x**powers)*(y**powers[::-1])
    values.append(res.tolist())

You might also want to keep res as numpy arrays depending on what you want to do with the results.
